# Como fazer um array com atributos ou objetos de uma classe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Boa noite, sou iniciante no python e estou com uma dúvida de como fazer um array de um objeto ou classe. O meu programa principal contém uma função que faz recortes em texto, delimitando blocos e etc..Bem simples mesmo.
E tenho outro que só  deixo as classes e os objetos, determinando a os tipos de cada atributo.A função funciona corretamente,porem não consigo chamar o atributos das Classes do meu pacote.

## A estrutura da função precisa ficar dessa forma.

```
Nome = RecortaTexto(Offset,Bloco,Loja.Esqueleto.Nome.Valor_I,Loja.Esqueleto.Nome.Valor_I)
```

## Programa Principal

```
from library.Tipos import Loja, Esqueleto, Modo

# Da o que está entre o inicio e o fim em determinado texto, respeitando offset e retornando offset inclusive.
def CortaFora(Offset,Texto,Inicio,Fim): 
    Inicial = Final = ''
    Inicial = PosEx(Inicio, Texto, Offset) + len(Inicio)
    Offset = Inicial
    Final = PosEx(Fim, Texto, Offset)
    Offset = Final
    return Texto[ Inicial:Final ].strip(' '), Offset

Offset = 0

Texto = '<h1 Teste </h1>'


Nome, Offset = CortaFora(Offset,Texto, Loja.Esqueleto.Valor_I, Loja.Esqueleto.Valor_F)

print(Nome)
```

## Pacote onde armazenei as classes

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Modo(object):
   Descricao = str
   Valor_I = (data['Valor_I'])
   Valor_F = (data['Valor_F'])
   Versao = int 

class Esqueleto(object):
   Esqueleto = Modo()
   PRODUTO = int
   PRECOS  = int
   NOME   = str
   NOME2   = int

class Loja:
   ID = int # ID da Loja
   SID = str # ID em String da Loja para evitar conversão em mil lugares.
   Cron = str  # Cron
   Nome = str
   Esqueleto = [Modo] #Aqui tentei fazer o Esqueleto sendo um array de modo
```

A intenção é fazer Loja receber um objeto de Esqueleto que recebe valor_I e valor_F. Conforme o exemplo solicitado a mim. Agradeço a quem puderme ajudar, e desculpas se não ficou claro meu problema.

Comment: Bom deixa ver se entendi, você quer que sua classe Loja no atributo esqueleto, receba os valores da classe Esqueleto como uma lista, é isso? Outra pergunta, sua classe esqueleto tem um atributo Esqueleto ali com a instância da classe Modo, sua intenção era herdar os atributos da classe Modo ou você precisa criar uma instância da classe mesmo?

Comment: Bom dia, preciso criar uma instacia da classe mesmo. A questão do atributo esqueleto e um dos meus problema, pois queria fazer ele entendendo que esqueleto recebe um array de Modo . No caso , se eu escolher 'PRODUTO' ele precisara receber Valor_I, e Valor_F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo da classe `Esqueleto` com o método construtor.

Para testar salve este código no arquivo `esqueleto.py`.

```
class Esqueleto():

    def __init__(self, nome, produto, preco):
        self.nome = nome
        self.produto = produto
        self.preco = preco
```

Crie um arquivo chama `main.py` e cole este código:

```
from esqueleto import Esqueleto

produto1 = Esqueleto("Tirol", "Leite Integral", 2.35)
produto2 = Esqueleto("Holandesa", "Queijo Prato", 8.99)
produto3 = Esqueleto("Nestlé", "Nescafé", 2.97)

lista = []

lista.append(produto1)
lista.append(produto2)
lista.append(produto3)

# Percorrendo a lista e imprimindo os produtos    

for produto in lista:
    print(produto.nome)
    print(produto.produto)
    print(produto.preco)
    print("\n")    

# Para imprimir cada índice da lista

print(lista[0].nome, lista[0].produto, lista[0].preco)
print(lista[1].nome, lista[1].produto, lista[1].preco)
print(lista[2].nome, lista[2].produto, lista[2].preco)
```

Note que na primeira linha do arquivo `main.py` o módulo `esqueleto` foi importado para que a classe `Esqueleto` esteja disponível para ser instanciada neste arquivo.

Rode o arquivo `main.py` para testar as saídas.

Comment: Eu nomearia esta classe como Produto. Não vejo muito sentido no nome Esqueleto, mas mantive para deixar mais próximo da tua lógica. Caso mude o nome, não esqueça de atualizar o import no arquivo main.py.

Answer (score 1):

Ola O código do Éder esta bem completo, com um código muito bom, aconselho que implemente e tente ver se te encaixa perfeitamente, entretanto quero dizer que se pretende continuar com sua implementação e queria apenas uma solução para criar a lista da classe `Modo` no atributo da classe `Loja` segue uma implementação bem simples para obter todos os dados de uma classe e transformar em uma lista

```py
class Modo(object):
   descricao = ''
   valor_I = ''
   valor_F = ''
   versao = ''

class Esqueleto(object):
   produto = ''
   preco  = ''
   nome   = ''
   nome2   = ''

class Loja:
   Id = '' # ID da Loja
   sid = '' # ID em String da Loja para evitar conversão em mil lugares.
   cron = ''  # Cron
   nome = ''
   esqueleto = [] #Aqui tentei fazer o Esqueleto sendo um array de modo

# Criando uma instancia da classe Modo, e preenchendo todos os atributos do objeto
m = Modo()
m.descricao = "Descrição"
m.valor_F = 15.2
m.valor_I = 85.55
m.versao = 1.0

# Mesma coisa com a classe Esqueleto
e = Esqueleto()
e.nome = "Um Nome"
e.nome2 = "Outro Nome"
e.preco = 5.10
e.produto = "PS4"
m.versao = 1.0

# Crio instancia da classe loja e no atributo esqueleto adiciono os valores preenchidos das classes anteriores.
loja = Loja()
loja.nome = "Minha Loja"
loja.sid = '12'
loja.Id = 12

# Transformando as classes Modo e Esqueleto como um dicionario
mdict = m.__dict__
edict = e.__dict__

# Adiciona dentro do atributo esqueleto da classe loja os valores do dicionario convertendo para lista
loja.esqueleto.append(list(mdict.values()))
loja.esqueleto.append(list(edict.values()))

print(loja.esqueleto) # [['Descrição', 15.2, 85.55, 1.0], ['Um Nome', 'Outro Nome', 5.1, 'PS4']]

# Caso prefira adicionar o dicionario completo das classes, ao invés dos valores apenas, basta adicionar o edict e o mdict, ficando assim loja.esqueleto.append(mdict)
```

Lembrando que aconselho você a construir suas classe como o Éder mostrou na resposta anterior, porque da forma como ele criar, cada instancia da sua classe terá um valor especifico, e como você implementou todas as instancias terão acesso a esses valores, pois foram criados como atributos de classe. Caso não tenha muita familiaridade com classes em python aconselho da uma lida na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) para ter uma visão global de classes em python.